# Linq Select Certain Properties Into Another Object?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq, .net-3.5

So say I have a collection of Bloops

```
Class Bloop
  Public FirstName
  Public LastName
  Public Address
  Public Number
  Public OtherStuff
End Class
```

Then I have a class of Razzies

```
Class Razzie
  Public FirstName
  Public LastName
End Class
```

Is it possible using Linq to select the FirstName and LastName out of all the Bloops in the collection of Bloops and return a collection of Razzies?  Or am i limited to a For-Loop to do my work?

To clear up any confusion, either VB or C# will do.  Also this will probably lead to me asking the question of (What about using a "Where" clause).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
Dim results = From item In bloops _
              Select New Razzie() With _
              { _
                  .FirstName = item.FirstName, _
                  .LastName = item.LastName _
              }
```

And if you want to convert the result from `IEnumerable<Bloop>` (what the LINQ query returns) to an array or `List<Bloop>`, just append a call to the `ToArray()` or `ToList()` extension methods respectively.

Edit: Corrected the code so that it now has valid VB.NET 9 syntax.

Comment: Fair enough. I just thought you'd prefer it in VB.NET since that's what your code samples were in. :)

Comment: can you edit your post to be correct c# syntax, as it is not correct vb syntax.  that way i can better understand what is going on.

Comment: @Noldorin re: other comment... thanks. indeed I had misread it. For some reason I read it as him having two collections.

Comment: @Russ: Ah, those darn underscores. Completely forgot about them! Should compile fine now.

Comment: Which aren't necessary anymore in VB.NET 10 (Implicit Line Continuation) Hurray!

Answer (score 46):

```
List<Bloop> myBloops = new List<Bloops>;
//populate myRazzies
List<Razzie> myRazzies = myBloops.Select(x => new Razzie() { FirstName = x.FirstName, LastName = x.LastName}).ToList();
```

Comment: C# is one of the tags listed in the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void Linq9()
{
    string[] words = { "aPPLE", "BlUeBeRrY", "cHeRry" };

    var upperLowerWords =
        from w in words
        select new { Upper = w.ToUpper(), Lower = w.ToLower() };

    foreach (var ul in upperLowerWords)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Uppercase: {0}, Lowercase: {1}", ul.Upper, ul.Lower);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Transforming from one type into another can be accomplished by using [Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx)

In fact, there is a [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336758.aspx) from 101 linq samples that shows a query transforming ints into strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
        C# Sample - Thanks to earlier posters.

        List<clsObj> myList = new List<clsObj>();
        clsObj clsObjInstance = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            clsObjInstance = new clsObj() { x = (i+1) % 3, a = "A" + i.ToString() };
            myList.Add(clsObjInstance);
        }

        List<int> extIntList = myList.Select(u => u.x).ToList();
        foreach (int u in extIntList)
            Console.Write(u.ToString() + "\t");

        List<string> extStringList = myList.Select(u => u.a).ToList();
        foreach (string u in extStringList)
            Console.Write(u + "\t");
```