# C# Linq question

Tags: c#, linq, operation

Does `LINQ` have a sequence operator, which allows to perform some action on every element without projecting it to a new sequence?

*This might see a bit awkward, but just for me to know :)*

Example:

```
IEnumerable<IDisposable> x;
x.PERFORM_ACTION_ON_EVERY_ELEMENT(m => m.Dispose());
```

*Obviously, this could be done using something like:*

```
foreach (var element in x) x.Dispose();
```

**But if something actually exists, that would be nice.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it doesn't exist. Specifically for the reason you mention: It seems awkward having a single operator that behaves completely different than all the others.

Eric Lippert, one of the C# Compiler developers [has an article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) about this.

> But we can go a bit deeper here. I am philosophically opposed to providing such a method, for two reasons.
>
> The first reason is that doing so violates the functional programming principles that all the other sequence operators are based upon. Clearly the sole purpose of a call to this method is to cause side effects.
>
> The purpose of an expression is to compute a value, not to cause a side effect. The purpose of a statement is to cause a side effect. The call site of this thing would look an awful lot like an expression (though, admittedly, since the method is void-returning, the expression could only be used in a “statement expression” context.)
>
> It does not sit well with me to make the one and only sequence operator that is only useful for its side effects.

Comment: Exactly. None of the other LINQ operators really ever expect their operations to have side effects, but this one is designed only for side effects.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the behavior would not be obvious; would it use deferred execution (as the other querying operators in LINQ-to-Objects like `Where` and `Select`), which could result in incomplete application of the operation, or would it be evaluated at call time? Would it support composition (in other words, would it return `IEnumerable<T>`, or would it be a `void` function? Etc., etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this method:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var t in source)
        {
            action(t);
        }
        return source;
    }
}
```

It returns the source so you can pass it along to another extension method as needed.  Or if you want to be void, you can change the method a little bit.

Comment: This would have been my answer. You can also use Select() in certain cases where a lambda both has a side effect and produces a result, but this is the way to do it for a void-returning lambda.

Comment: I was thinking about this just yesterday; unfortunately actually using this method results in about as much typing as a one-liner `foreach` :P

Answer (score 2):

The [morelinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) project has a `ForEach` operator. LINQ itself doesn't, as LINQ is all about functional programming, and `ForEach` has side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar dicussion on this [Run a method on all objects within a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928216/run-a-method-on-all-objects-within-a-collection)