# how to store value of queries in string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have to store value of the column CityName and StateAbbr in two strings in following query how can i do this using only one query

```
var GetLocation= (
      from results in db1.ZipCodes1 
      where results.ZIPCode==zipcode 
      select new { results.CityName, results.StateAbbr }
).First();
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923238/linq-select-certain-properties-into-another-object) question for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want

```
 string CityName = GetLocation.CityName;
 string  StateAbbr = GetLocation.StateAbbr;
```