# How to filterout specific fields from a linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model with a field that has a member variable referencing the same class. Now I want to query the data and its child items but I only want to output certain members and filter the others.

Example model:

```
public class ContentModel
{
    public string Name;
    public string Url;
    public string x, y, z // filter this
    public IEnumerable<ContentModel> Children;
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
  "Name": "",
  "Url": "",
  "Child": {
    "Name": "",
    "Url": "",
    "Child": {
      "Name": "",
      "Url": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried and the code containing the list itself. In general projections are done using `.Select`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq Select Certain Properties Into Another Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923238/linq-select-certain-properties-into-another-object)

Comment: Shouldn't Children be a list object or just be one child?  Models are not hierarchical. They are in table format so you need to recursively get each level of hierarchical.  I will wok on sample.

Comment: It should be a IEnumerable<ContentModel> Children;

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169648/how-to-exclude-property-from-json-serialization

Comment: Your model is wrong.  See my answer.  A database contains tables with rows.  So the model is an IEnumerable table.  The children are not IEnumerable.  A database table is a two dimensional array and cells are not IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered questions like this hundreds of times.  Normally you have a flat database table where each row contains the parents name and child name.  Then you create a tree recursively.  Here is an example of the code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace ConsoleApplication108
{
    class Program
    {
        static DataBase db = new DataBase();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string parentName = string.Empty;
            Tree root = new Tree();
            GetTreeRecursively(parentName, root);
        }
        static void GetTreeRecursively(string parentName, Tree parent )
        {
            foreach (ContentModel model in db.contentModel.Where(x => x.parentName == parentName))
            {
                if (parent.children == null) parent.children = new List<Tree>();
                Tree newChild = new Tree();
                parent.children.Add(newChild);
                newChild.url = model.url;
                string name = model.name;
                newChild.name = name;
                GetTreeRecursively(name, newChild);
            }
        }
    }
    public class DataBase
    {
        public List<ContentModel> contentModel { get; set; }
    }
    public class ContentModel
    {
        public string parentName  { get;set;}
        public string url { get;set;}
        public string x  { get;set;}
        public string y { get;set;}
        public string z  { get;set;}
        public string name;
    }
    public class Tree
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public List<Tree> children { get; set; }
    }
}
```